# Using Windows XP as a SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, windows-xp, sql-server-express

I was wondering if anyone knew of any limitations to using Windows XP as a File and SQL server. I am asking because one of the applications we sell, requires the customer to setup a server for filesharing and as a SQL Server. We already allow them to use SQL Express, but we wanted to see if we can suggest Windows XP as a low cost alternative to Windows Server. The only potential problem that I could see if there were limits on the number of concurrent connections to either the files or the database. We are only thinking of recommending this for smaller sized companies who would have 10-15 users.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is a [limit of 10 inbound connections](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=314882) on XP professional, and 5 on XP Home. So it would only be practicable for a very small company.

Answer (score 3):

From this MS KB Article:

> Note For Windows XP Professional, the
>   maximum number of other computers that
>   are permitted to simultaneously
>   connect over the network is ten. This
>   limit includes all transports and
>   resource sharing protocols combined.
>   For Windows XP Home Edition, the
>   maximum number of other computers that
>   are permitted to simultaneously
>   connect over the network is five. This
>   limit is the number of simultaneous
>   sessions from other computers the
>   system is permitted to host. This
>   limit does not apply to the use of
>   administrative tools that attach from
>   a remote computer.
>
> Per development: The connection limit
>   refers to the number of
>   redirector-based connections and is
>   enforced for any file, print, named
>   pipe, or mail slot session. The TCP
>   connection limit is not enforced, but
>   it may be bound by legal agreement to
>   not permit more than 10 clients.

I suggest reading [the kb article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314882) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you can run SQL Server Standard or Workgroup Edition on Windows XP Pro. It is not limited to the express version ...

Answer (score 0):

One cost effective alternative is [Windows Small Business Server](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_Business_Server).
[SBS 2003 R2: Features at a Glance](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/sbs/evaluation/features/default.mspx)

Answer (score 0):

This will break the EULA.

Here is the relevant knowledge base [article](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?kbid=314882). Note that while TCP connection limits are *not* enforced for XP, legally they are limited to 10 connections.

Small business server seems like a better fit, and is cost effective if you shop around.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with Small Business Server is all the frill it comes with that is unnecessary for a simple file and sql server; like exchange server, sharepoint, etc. I've used Windows XP as a small business SQL/File server, but as others have pointed out, you are limited to 10 connections legally speaking.

Answer (score 0):

Another issue with Small Business Server is it can't be installed on an existing domain. Your best bet would be to package the SQL Server portion around a normal Windows server installation. If you're looking at 10-15 users, there's no guarantee that they have a domain. But if they don't, likely they are already dealing with the file server problem using accounts with same usernames/passwords on the file server(s) as on their individual workstations.

Answer (score -1):

The number of connections is not related to SQL Server edition, but to the operating system. For example, Windows XP allows only 10 concurrent connections, Windows 7 20. For Windows Server OS [no need to purchase any new server machine ], the number of connections is unlimited (but you can limit is using Terminal Services).
The error message shown in case of connection limit reached is something like "the security limit reached...the number of concurrent connect attempts"

Answer (score -3):

Presumably you are meaning SQL Express, as you can't run SQL Server on XP, it's a server product.

If the customer can afford your product, they can afford a copy of Server 2003, or whatever, the file sharing's built-in.  Admittedly SQL Server's fairly expensive, but if your product needs it, that's the way it goes.  If cost were an issue, you shouldn't be using SQL Server as the database platform.  There's no point in trying to force a server-based solution into a client OS.  You'll end up with all sorts of problems before long.

Doesn't the client have a domain-based infrastructure already?

The upshot being being if the client has 5-10 users of the software, they should be on SBS anyway for a variety of other reasons.  You don't get SQL Server with it though.

(Samba would be an option for file-sharing, but doubtless more expensive than simply buying Server 2003 in this instance).